# Cauchy integral whose integrand has pole as singularity

Tags: complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula, singularity

integration[1/(z-2)(z^3 - 1)^5] on |z|=1
Which of the following is true?

1. 2×pi×i/(2^15 - 1)
2. -2×pi×i/(2^15 - 1)
3. 2×pi×i/7^5
4. -2×pi×i/7^5

I've tried hard but I failed, since my confusion is about

- is "1" a point of singularity, since it lies **on** the circle
- the process is too long and too calculative to me so that I can't find any solutions.

*I'm sure I'm mistaking somewhere, it can't so long.But where I'm overlooking I can't find.*

Please help me to find this, please in the answer section rather in comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Please use MathJax . See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Big  big issue with this question, the integrand is blowing up on the unit circle. I am sure there is some typo in the question, otherwise it is just striaght up wrong.

Comment: @actoh sir Answer is given option 3, why sir this is wrong? I mean what's the problem if the pole is in boundary?

Answer (score 1):

*If* 1/(z-2)(z^3 - 1)^5 means $\frac1{(z-2)(z^3-1)^5}$, then the question doesn't make sense, since, as you noticed, that function  is not defined at all the points of the unit circle.

Comment: sir, you wrote right, that is the function and I also expressed my doubts on that. What's about the point "1"? I'm stuck really.

Comment: Didn't you understand that I agree with you? I'll say it again: **the question doesn't make sense**.

Comment: Ok sir. I got it now.

Comment: Sir answer is given option 3.My question why this question is wrong? What's wrong in it if the  pole lies on the boundary?

Comment: Then the integral along the unit circle makes no sense, since the function is not defined for every point of that circle.

Comment: Are you sure that the question mentions $\lvert z\rvert=1$?

Comment: Yes sir. There is no typo in my question sir.